# How to load data from azure to a xamarin form using data binding

Tags: database, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I am currently having a problem loading data from my azure database to my Xamarin forms listview. The problem I have is by my GetTaskAsync statement, I have modified the controller and now it builds but gives me a System.

TpyeInitializationException error message when I try to get data from my DB. As a template, I mainly used the todo list example as a way to get my data as they both share the same DB but without any luck. Any advice will be appreciated. Please if you can point out where I went wrong or have any examples I can see to get a better idea on my problem I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

```
public partial class ContinentController
{
    static ContinentController defaultInstance = new ContinentController();
    MobileServiceClient client;

    IMobileServiceTable<Continent> continentTable;


    private ContinentController()
    {
        this.client = new MobileServiceClient(
            Constants.ApplicationURL);

        this.continentTable = client.GetTable<Continent>();
    }

    public static ContinentController DefaultManager
    {
        get
        {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
        private set
        {
            defaultInstance = value;
        }
    }

    public MobileServiceClient CurrentClient
    {
        get { return client; }
    }
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Continent>> GetContinentsAsync(bool syncItems = false)
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<Continent> items = await continentTable
                .Where(c => c.ContinentName == "Africa")
                .ToEnumerableAsync();

            return new ObservableCollection<Continent>(items);
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"Invalid sync operation: {0}", msioe.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"Sync error: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is a screen shot of my current error:

[image: Xamarin Studio Error in xaml view page]

Comment: It is hard to say from the code you have provided what actually is wrong. You need to provide a stack trace, maybe more information about what `continentTable` is and how you have set that up. If something is null, it is probably because you have forgot something.

Comment: @Cheesebaron, good morning. Just to clarify a bit, the continentTable is linked to my Continent.Cs which is my model in this case. The model contains get n set statements for continentid and continentname. Am not sure how to send a screenshot here, can I have your email to send the screen shot I took?

Comment: Edit your question and attach a screenshot there. Discussion should be kept here for people to be able to refer to your question in the future. Spend some time narrowing down and finding out why you get a null reference. Use the debugger to your advantage.

Comment: @Cheesebaron, I have uploaded the screen shot. Based on what I was trying to change I still believe the main error is still with my get statement.

Comment: You need to step into the initialization of your Controller and see what is going on there. Use the debugger, set some break points, inspect the values, see what is going on.

Comment: @Cheesbaron, i have done as you suggested and found that my issue was that my Id was null. I was under the impression that when I declared ContinentId this would be the default ID for my application.